# Doing Math with 2 Subquerys

Tags: sql, informix

I have two subquerys both calculating sums. I would like to do an Artithmetic Minus(-) with  the result of both Querys . eg Query1: 400 Query2: 300 Result should be 100.

Obvious a basic - in the query does not work. The minus works as MINUS on sets. How can I solve this? Do you have any ideas?

```
SELECT CustumersNo FROM Custumers WHERE
(
SELECT SUM(value) FROM roe WHERE roe.credit = Custumers.CustumersNo 
-
SELECT SUM(value) FROM roe WHERE roe.debit = Custumers.CustumersNo
)
> 500
```

Using Informix - sorry missed that point

Comment: Which SQL? SQL SERVER, MySQL etc.

Comment: this should be working fine with mysql operators, what dbms u r using ?

Comment: Your syntax looks valid for ANSI/ISO SQL.  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `SELECT SUM ... = Customers.CustomersNo` statements in brackets?

Comment: Yes, I have problems with it. This query returns only a subset of the real result (). My guess: When one person does not have a SUM of credit or debit the DBMS returns a NULL with that subquery, which cause some misbehavior on the MINUS...

Comment: @acatt: yep, i tried it!

Comment: @Johannes: could you use the `NVL` function to replace `value` with `0` if it's `null`?  Eg `SUM(NVL(value, 0))`

Comment: @acatt: Thanks that helped to solve my problem!

Comment: SUM() only adds non-null values; the problem is when SUM() works on no rows, in which case the result is NULL (rather than 0).  So NVL(SUM(value), 0) would be more accurate/relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the original syntax to work, you would need to surround the sub-selects in parentheses:

```
SELECT CustumersNo
  FROM Custumers
 WHERE ((SELECT SUM(value) FROM roe WHERE roe.credit = Custumers.CustumersNo) 
        -
        (SELECT SUM(value) FROM roe WHERE roe.debit  = Custumers.CustumersNo)
       ) > 500
```

Note that aggregates are defined to ignore nulls in the values they aggregate in standard SQL.  However, the SUM of an empty set of rows is NULL, not zero.

You can get inventive and devise ways to always have a value for each customer listed in the `roe` table, such as:

```
SELECT CustomersNo
  FROM (SELECT CustomersNo, SUM(value) AS net_credit
          FROM (SELECT credit AS CustomersNo, +value
                UNION
                SELECT debit  AS CustomersNo, -value
               ) AS x
         GROUP BY CustomersNo
       ) AS y
 WHERE net_credit > 500;
```

You can also do that with an appropriate HAVING clause if you wish.  Note that this avoids issues with customers who have credit entries but no debit entries or vice versa; all the entries that are present are treated appropriately.

---

Your misspelling (or unorthodox spelling) of 'customers' is nearly as good as 'costumers'.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I'm sorry for my misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

Something like what you tried should work.  It may be a syntax problem, and it may depend on what type of SQL you are using.  However, an approach like this would be more efficient:

**Update:** I see you were having a problem with nulls, so I updated it to handle nulls properly.

```
select CustumersNo from (
    select CustumersNo, 
           sum(coalesce(roecredit.value,0)) - sum(coalesce(roedebit.value,0)) 
               as balance 
        FROM Custumers 
        join roe roecredit on roe.credit = Custumers.CustumersNo 
        join roe roedebit on roe.debit = Custumers.CustumersNo 
        group by CustumersNo
    )
    where balance > 500
```

*Caveat: I don't have experience with Informix specifically.*

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution.